# Problema en la replicación local subscription y local publication SQL Server Managment Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, server, ssms, sql-server-management

Estoy creando una base de datos distribuida y necesita configurar la replicación, pero se supone que debería aparecer las carpetas así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Con la carpeta de replication y 2 carpetas dentro, una de local suscription y la otra de Local publication **

Sin embargo, sólo me aparece así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

** Sólo la carpeta de Local Suscriptions**

Ayuda por favor

Answer (score 0):

¿Cuál edición de SQL Server estás usando? Lo más seguro es que sea porque es la edición Express y solo soporta subscripciones y no publicaciones (porque no tiene agente).

Si lo necesitas para un entorno productivo, hay que pagar licencias. Si es para aprender y probar, puedes obtener la edición Developer.

Comment: Osea en la edición Developer si me va a funcionar sin licencia??

Comment: La licencia de Developer es gratuita y tiene todas las funciones de la versión Enterprise, pero no se puede usar para ambientes productivos.